# How to count the number of binary 1's in MIPS code?

Tags: binary, mips

First, I started this work by typing up a C-code that counted the number of binary 1's in a positive number. I found it easier to type C-code first and then try to convert it. My C-code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int num;
   int remainder;
   int one_count=0;
   int input_num;

   printf("Please enter a positive integer: ");
   scanf("%d",&num);
   input_num = num;

   while (num > 0)
   {
    remainder = num % 2;
    if(remainder == 1)
      {
       one_count++;
      }
     printf("%d\n",num);
     num = num/2;

   }
   printf("The number of 1's in %d",input_num);
   printf(" is %d\n.",one_count);

 return 0;
}
```

Now, I tried to convert this to MIPS without using pointers but I keep getting zero as an answer even though I think my logic is right. I pretty much just went down the line in C-code and attempted to convert it into MIPS. I am suppose to use $sp, but for now I am just trying to get it to count the right number and then I will attempt to implement the stack. My attemps at MIPS code is as follows:

```
    .data
   Prompt1:.asciiz "Please enter a positive integer: "
   Prompt2:.asciiz "in "
   Prompt3:.asciiz " is "
   Result: .asciiz "The number of 1's "
    .text
  main:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, Prompt1
    syscall

 #get user entered number
 li $v0,5
 syscall
 move $s0,$v0
 move $s1,$v0

 li $v0,4
 la $a0, Result
 syscall

 li $v0,4
 la $a0, Prompt2
 syscall


 move $a0,$s1
 li $v0,1
 syscall

 li $v0,4
 la $a0, Prompt3
 syscall

 move $a0,$t4
 li $v0,1
 syscall




onecount:

  li $t5,1            #to set remainder equal to 1
  li $t2,2            # to divide num by two


  ble $s1,$0,exit     #if $s1(num <=0), jump to exit
  rem $s2, $s0,$t2    # hold modulus in $s2

  bnez $s2, increment #if ($s2(remainder) != 0), jump to increment and do        .                                                    # one_count++
  div $s1,$t2         # num = num /2


increment:
  addi $t4,$t4,1      # one_count++ to count number of 1's in $t4 

  j onecount          #jump back to one count until num equal to zero

exit:

 li $v0,10
 syscall
```

Right now, all this output gives me is zero and it continually runs. I believe I set it up correctly to how the C-code is set up but obviously not. Any help would be great if anyone knows where I am going wrong.

Comment: 1) `$s1` is never modified in the `onecount` loop. 2) `lt` means Less Than, but what you probably want is `le`.

Comment: @Michael so you are saying that the (blt $s1, $s0, exit) should be "ble" instead? if so, wouldn't that just be checking if the number entered was equal to zero and less than? That is a good catch because I do need to check for that but I still end up getting zero as an output.

Comment: The C `while` loop continues as long as `num > 0`. The corresponding "exit if` would be `num <= 0`, hence you want `ble`. But like I said in my first comment, you're never modifying `$s1` within the loop, so I don't know how you expected the loop to ever finish. Also, your `increment` code will be executed regardless of the value of the remainder; you're discarding the output of the `div` instruction; and using `div`/`rem` for this is overkill in the first place when you could use `srl`/`andi` instead..  Consult a MIPS instruction set reference.

Comment: @Michael so I added the comments of what I believe each line of code is doing. Could you let me know if any of the lines are wrong? Thank you for helping with the redundancy with the divide and error lines.

Comment: I just realized how much harder this is since MIPS doesn't have a carry flag.